# MySQL Filter databse query by time and look for duplicates

Tags: mysql, wordpress, time, duplicates

I am running a query based on previous answers I have found for wordpress. I wish to look for duplicates 'track' posts within the last half an hour. I want to display all duplicates and ignore the first post within that time period.

I have taken a solution I found and added in the time function but I am seeing all posts including the original post, it is not removing the first post. I believe this may be because it is searching all post entires in the table and then adding in the time filter. I have tried adding the time filter into the select function but it brings up an error saying unknown post_date column.

The below gives me all duplicates within the last half an hour, I need it to remove the first entry.

```
SELECT a. *
FROM wp_posts AS a
   INNER JOIN (
      SELECT post_title, MIN( id ) AS min_id
      FROM wp_posts
      WHERE post_type = 'track'
      AND post_status = 'publish'
      GROUP BY post_title
      HAVING COUNT( * ) > 1
   ) AS b ON b.post_title = a.post_title
AND b.min_id <> a.id
AND a.post_type = 'track'
AND a.post_status = 'publish'
AND a.post_date > subtime(now(),'0:30:0')
```

The expected result would be all duplicates within the last half an hour and it will not display the original post. Currently it gives me all duplicates and the original.

Comment: I have tried your select query and it works fine and it doesn't matter if the original is in the time limit or not. I would post my select where i reduce wp_posts to the needed minimum, but as long as i can't see what you made in the first place it is not an answer

Comment: Hi nbk thanks for the response. I think maybe you have missed the point. I am not concerned with any entries made at any point apart from within the last 30 minutes. So for example, if I look at my posts over the last 30 minutes on my website I can see that a post was made with the title 'Electricity'. It was first made at 10.11, then repeated at 10.12, 10.13 and 10.14. When the query runs I'd expect to only see entries 10.12, 10.13 and 10.14. 10.11 can be ignored because it is the original so can be omitted from the results.

Comment: I tried your select in sqlfiddle and i never get the first because of the b.min_id <> a.id you never can get the 10.11. On big databases your solution checks all rows and you can make it faster by reducing it to the needed rows.. but i still can't understand your problem, can you add rows here to show your point? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/35d96f/3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, sure I tried this earlier but suddenly it worked. Here is the final answer.

```
SELECT a. *
FROM wp_posts AS a
   INNER JOIN (
      SELECT post_title, MIN( id ) AS min_id
      FROM wp_posts
      WHERE post_type = 'track'
      AND post_status = 'publish'
      AND post_date > subtime(now(),'0:30:0')
      GROUP BY post_title
      HAVING COUNT( * ) > 1
   ) AS b ON b.post_title = a.post_title
AND b.min_id <> a.id
AND a.post_type = 'track'
AND a.post_status = 'publish'
AND a.post_date > subtime(now(),'0:30:0');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT w1.*
FROM wp_posts AS w1
INNER JOIN wp_posts AS w2 ON w1.post_title = w2.post_title 
WHERE w1.id > w2.id 
    AND (w1.post_type, w2.post_type) = ('track', 'track')
    AND (w1.post_status, w2.post_status) = ('publish', 'publish')
     AND w1.post_date > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE 
     AND w2.post_date > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE;

Update: Remove older records from both tables and apply relevant filters on both.
```

Explanation:

- Inner join based on post_title will create N*N records of a single value of post_title. e.g. If there are 3 posts with the title 'A' then there would be 9 records.
- Now we will compare and remove the record with smallest id from first table w1(considering the first table as base and output producing table).
- Now result set contains (N-1)* N records, as we removed all mapping of the oldest post, ***Now this will remove the oldest record(within 30 minutes) from the first table***.
- Remove all posts which do not have post_type as track and not published from the table w1.
- Finally, remove posts older than 30 minutes.
- The result would contain the posts but they are duplicated with w2 table, so remove duplicates and select data from w1 only.

Comment: Hi there thanks so much for the response. I have tried your code and it does not fix the issue. e.g., If I look at my posts over the last 30 minutes on my website I can see that a post was made with the title 'Electricity'. It was first made at 10.11, then repeated at 10.12, 10.13 and 10.14. If I run your query in the database I get the same issue as with mine, all 4 entries show up. When the query runs I'd expect to only see entries 10.12, 10.13 and 10.14. How can we adapt to give me this?

Comment: I've pasted my solution above. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: I see you want to exclude the first record within 30 minutes, not the actual first oldest record. My query removes the very first record, not the first in the last 30 minutes. So it must be having 'Electricity' titled post before 10.11 but before 30 minutes. I will provide you an update:) Let me know if I missed anything.

Comment: @vinyllicker, updated the solution, let me know how it works for you.

Comment: nice man, also an answer that works. I've tested on my data using both yours and mine above and both work with similar speed. Thanks for your help.